# Getting .htaccess file on Apache server? (Removing html from url)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I cannot get the .htaccess file in my htdocs folder. Google only keeps showing me tutorials on  removing the # from 'LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so' inside httpd.conf and when I went to do this, the # was already removed. Then find AccessFileName inside httpd.conf, which I could not find. Well it didn't auto generate a .htaccess file (assuming it's suppose to). So I made my own .htaccess.txt file. Then I put this* in there, hoping to remove html from my urls (it's from a tutorial remoivng php, I was hoping it had the same concept) but it didn't work.

Can anybody help me?

*This is what I put:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mod_rewrite rule you can simply add this line in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

This will allow you to access your various files without extensions.

Comment: So just RewriteEnine On
Options +MultiViews?

Comment: No just this line `Options +MultiViews` You don't need `RewriteEnine On `

Comment: Is .htaccess enabled? Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: It didn't give me a 500 error. It should be enabled because it doesn't show it in the directory tree of my website.

Comment: If by putting random text in .htaccess you didn't get 500 then .htaccess is not enabled.